# Verify the Login without do it

Tags: apex, community, login

I'm working with a Salesforce Customer Community and I was wondering if is possible, given a username and a password, check if this credential is good or not without invoking the ***Site.login(***) method.

I'm implementing a Visualforce Page on the Community where I collect that information:

- Current Username
- Password
- New Username

If the user types the correct Current Username and Password, I will update its Current Username with the new one. This operation is exectued using the Guest User and for this reason I don't want to invoke the **Site.login()** method.

For this reason, I am looking for a method to check if the Username/Password are correct in order to complete the process.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read up on what an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) is and explain this *other process*. Because the way you are going about it sounds questionable.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have just updated the post. Let me know if now is clear. Thanks

Comment: Site.login or its REST/SOAP equivalent is that method